# Updating values between two dataframes in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

Working with Databricks PySpark

I have two dataframes

ROUGH IDEA -
api_df -

```
+-------------+----------+-----------+
|           id|safeNumber|portfolioId|
+-------------+----------+-----------+
|GB-0-08872332|UK09208902|    1697451|
|GB-0-09326157|UK13305196|    1697451|
|GB-0-08581699|UK08891382|    1697451|
|GB-0-07803632|UK08035068|    1697451|
+-------------+----------+-----------+
```

creditsafe_data -

```
+---------------+-----------+------------+---------------+-----------+---------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|merchant_reg_id|safe_number|portfolio_id|notification_id|register_id|data_json|            _in_z|            out_z|         batch_id|
+---------------+-----------+------------+---------------+-----------+---------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|  GB-0-08697274| UK09017868|     1697451|        1008974|       1101| datadata|13-10-23 11:11:00|14-10-23 11:11:32|13-19-23 11:11:00|
|  GB-0-08872332| UK09208902|     1697451|        1203001|       2247| somedata|22-10-23 12:10:22|25-12-23 12:30:00|22-10-23 17:40:00|
+---------------+-----------+------------+---------------+-----------+---------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Resulting creditsafe_data df after joins

```
+---------------+-----------+------------+---------------+-----------+---------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|merchant_reg_id|safe_number|portfolio_id|notification_id|register_id|data_json|            _in_z|            out_z|         batch_id|
+---------------+-----------+------------+---------------+-----------+---------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|  GB-0-00872332| UK09208902|     1697451|        1008974|       1101| datadata|13-10-23 11:11:00|14-10-23 11:11:32|13-19-23 11:11:00|
|  GB-0-09326157| UK13305196|     1697451|           null|       null|     null|             null|             null|             null|
|  GB-0-08581699| UK08891382|     1697451|           null|       null|     null|             null|             null|             null|
|  GB-0-07803632| UK08035068|     1697451|           null|       null|     null|             null|             null|             null|
+---------------+-----------+------------+---------------+-----------+---------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

THINGS TO NOTE:

1. Notice how api_df.id has value 'GB-0-08872332' present in creditsafe_data.merchant_reg_id as well. If this is the case , then don't do anything to the creditsafe_data's merchant_reg_id 'GB-0-08872332' row
2. Notice how GB-0-09326157, GB-0-08581699,GB-0-07803632 are only present in api_df.id but are not present in creditsafe_data.merchant_reg_id, if this is the case then add GB-0-09326157, GB-0-08581699,GB-0-07803632 along with thier respective api_df.safeNumber and api_df.portfolioId to creditsafe_data.merchant_reg_id, creditsafe_data.safe_number and creditsafe_data.portfolio_id
3. Notice how creditsafe_data.merchant_reg_id GB-0-08697274 is not present in api_df.id. if this is the case delete that entire row from creditsafe_data dataframe.
   Hence resulting dataframe should look like this when creditsafe_data.display() is executed.

What would be the most efficient way to do this in pyspark ? Kindly help , i have just completed my computer degree in python and just started exploring pyspark. found something called creditsafe api and trying to generate alerts with free account. This was a sample test i'm trying out of my own interest. Kindly help as this would be a motivation for me in this difficult time of layoffs for freshers.

EDIT - Trying to work with something like this , haphazard code -

```
missing_ids = api_df.select("id").subtract(creditsafe_data.select("merchant_reg_id"))
missing_data = api_df.join(missing_ids, "id", "inner")
missing_data = missing_data.select("id", "safeNumber", "portfolioId")
missing_data = missing_data.withColumnRenamed("id", "merchant_reg_id").withColumnRenamed("safeNumber", "safe_number").withColumnRenamed("portfolioId", "portfolio_id")
creditsafe_data = creditsafe_data.union(missing_data)

to_delete = creditsafe_data.select("merchant_reg_id").subtract(api_df.select("id"))
creditsafe_data = creditsafe_data.join(to_delete, "merchant_reg_id", "left_anti")
creditsafe_data.show()
```

But end up getting

AnalysisException: [NUM_COLUMNS_MISMATCH] UNION can only be performed on inputs with the same number of columns, but the first input has 9 columns and the second input has 3 columns.;

Comment: No Mr.Dileep , I'm using databricks from https://www.databricks.com/ not the azure one.

Comment: please share the sources of data , i might be able to try something on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code which worked for me was this - but i might have to check for every other use case as well. But for now , posting this as the answer

```
result_df = api_df.join(creditsafe_data, api_df.id == creditsafe_data.merchant_reg_id, "left")
```

```
creditsafe_data = result_df.select(
    api_df.id.alias("merchant_reg_id"),
    api_df.safeNumber.alias("safe_number"),
    api_df.portfolioId.alias("portfolio_id"),
    creditsafe_data.merchant_reg_id.alias("notification_id"),
    creditsafe_data.register_id,
    creditsafe_data.data_json,
    creditsafe_data._in_z,
    creditsafe_data.out_z,
    creditsafe_data.batch_id
)
```